# Enlarge APFS container with free space

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, apfs

The container scheme of my hard drive is the following

[image]

I have more or less 87 GB free, that are not contained in this list.

I have removed the container of size 87 GB with the command

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

Now, If I use

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

I get the error

```
Started APFS operation
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required 
in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often
caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of 
another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

I think this is a problem of offset but I don't know how actually solve this problem. The command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e "Disk Size"`
 returns

```
Partition Offset:          188026839040 Bytes (45904990 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
Disk Size:                 63.0 GB (62973333504 Bytes) (exactly 122994792 512-Byte-Units)
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to backup your stuff, erase everything, reinstall macOS and restore from your backup. If this is not an acceptable solution, then post a comment.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes I know... but I would like to avoid this drastic solution.